# post photo to wall via app (not file uploading)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-wall

I have image folder on server, how to post photo pick from my image directory or generated by my application not by uploaded through form.

```
    $path = 'name/'.$user_id.'.jpg';
    $post_url = '/'.$user_id.'/photos'; 

    //post photo
    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
            //posts message on page statues 
            $msg_body = array(
            'source'=>'@'.realpath($path),
            'message' => 'like and share photo'
            );

        if ($user_id) {
          try {
                $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
          }
        }else{
         echo 'photo was not uploaded';
        }
        echo '<pre>'.print_r($postResult).'</pre>';
```

display print_r result: 
    **(#324) Requires upload file**

Comment: I’d say that’s not the print_r result, but the message of the exception your are getting when trying to post. Check your path value an what realpath makes of it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ask for "photo_upload" permission to do that.

Here's example using JavaScript SDK (php could be very similar):

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
      FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', { url: "http://yourimagehere.png" }, function(response) {
          if (!response || response.error) {
               console.log(response);
          } else {
               alert('OK');
          }
      });
   }
},{scope:'photo_upload'});
```

Above code will auto create new album "[YourAppName] Photos" in user albums and inserts there your image. Image will also should be posted to user wall (in case he didn't block that functionality in his/hers privacy policy).

It works for now ;)